# Can somebody help me with Pascal Lang?

Tags: pascal

I have a problem with understanding of lists in pascal and pointers. Somebody can help me with this?

- What does `^` mean?
- What does `^.` mean?

Answer (score 3):

`^datatype` means "pointer to datatype object"

`variable^` means "value to which variable points"

`@variable` means "address of variable"

Examples:

```
var
  value: integer; { value is an integer}
  pValue: ^integer; { pValue is a pointer on integer }
begin
  value := 0;
  pValue := @value; // "@value" is pointer on variable value
  pValue^ := 1; { set 1 to something on which pValue points (equal to value := 1) }
end.
```

You can read it in wiki: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pascal_Programming/Pointers

So, `^.` means `.` (access to member) applied to something on which variable points.
For example, if you have `pRectangle: ^Rectangle` (pointer on rectangle), you can get access to it's width: `pRectangle^.width`

Comment: +1, but `@` from my point of view more close to "address of variable" than to "pointer on variable".

Comment: `@` is the `address of` operator. It means "address of variable", not "pointer on variable". I'd change "pointer on datatype object" to "pointer to", and "value on" to "value to", but other than that this is correct (the differences are probably language related, meaning "English grammar" and not "Pascal vs something else").

Comment: ThinkJet and Ken White, thank you very much for betterments of my answer!